# CMake linking Windows SDK

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, include, static-libraries

I have a project in CLion in which I need to include a library from the Windows 8.1 SDK, so I attempted to use CMake to link it.
I don't have any .so or .dll, but .lib (or directly the .h file).
Specifically, this library is dsound.h.
I tried to look for related questions, but none of the solutions I found works for me: how can I do it?

My current CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(Project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(${WinSDK})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp file1.h file1.cpp)
add_executable(Project ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Project ${WinSDK})
```

where WinSDK is the variable containing the location of the Windows SDK.

The error I get is the following:

```
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Project.dir/main.cpp.obj
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Project.dir/soundclass.cpp.obj
In file included from C:\projectPath\soundclass.cpp:4:0:
C:\projectPath\soundclass.h:21:24: fatal error: dsound.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:\projectPath\main.cpp:5:0:
C:\projectPath\soundclass.h:21:24: fatal error: dsound.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles\Project.dir\build.make:61: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Project.dir/main.cpp.obj' failed
CMakeFiles\Project.dir\build.make:85: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Project.dir/soundclass.cpp.obj' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Project.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project.dir/soundclass.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Project.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'Project' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Project] Error 2
```

Comment: Where did you initialize the `WinSDK` variable? Somewhere in an upper scope? Are the header files located exactly in that location you stored in `WinSDK` variable?

Comment: The 'WinSDK' variable was defined in the Path Variables of CLion; now I changed it depending on include and library, as @utopia suggested, and it works.

Comment: My intention with my question was to make it sure that you set the exact location of headers and libraries or not. It looks like that was the root cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${WinSDK}` cannot be set correctly since you are using the same variable in the same way for both include and library.

Other tips:

- CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD does nothing for the MSVC compiler
- it is better to use `target_include_directories()` than `include_directories()` to keep target information cleaner

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Thank you also for the other tips.